# Compiling ImageMagick as 64bit under OS X?

Tags: macos, makefile, imagemagick, compilation, configure

I'm trying to install [moddims](http://code.google.com/p/moddims/) on OS X (see [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185106/how-do-i-configure-make-install-against-an-older-version-of-a-library)), an Apache module with a dependency on ImageMagick.

As far as I can tell, the OS X Apache is compiled as 64 bit. My previous attempt to run the  moddims module I had compiled gave the following error:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 117 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: 
Cannot load /usr/libexec/apache2/libmod_dims.so into server: 
dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/libmod_dims.so, 10): no suitable image found.  
Did find:\n\t/usr/libexec/apache2/libmod_dims.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I'm presuming that means I need to compile moddims as 64 bit... so I tried the following:

```
moddims-read-only simon$ ./configure CFLAGS='-arch x86_64' \
    APXSLDFLAGS='-arch x86_64' --with-curl=/usr/local/bin/ \
    --with-imagemagick=/opt/ImageMagick-6.3.9/
```

But that gave me this error:

```
checking for MagickWandGenesis in -lMagickWand... no
checking for MagickWandGenesis in -lWand... no
configure: error: ImageMagick not found.
```

Previously, when compiling without the CFLAGS 64 bit stuff, this had worked just fine.

So... I'm guessing this means I need to compile ImageMagick as 64bit. I tried the following:

```
ImageMagick-6.3.9 simon$ ./configure --prefix=/opt/ImageMagick-6.3.9/ \
    --exec-prefix=/opt/ImageMagick-6.3.9/ CFLAGS='-arch x86_64' \
    APXSLDFLAGS='-arch x86_64'
```

That ./configure command runs fine, but when I run `make` it trundles along happily for a while and then dies with this error:

```
/bin/sh ./libtool --silent --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -arch x86_64 -Wall -W -D_THREAD_SAFE -module -avoid-version -L/usr/X11/lib -R/usr/X11/lib -L/opt/local/lib -lfreetype -lz -o ltdl/dlopen.la  ltdl/loaders/dlopen.lo  
/bin/sh ./libtool --silent --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -arch x86_64 -Wall -W -D_THREAD_SAFE -no-undefined -dlpreopen ltdl/dlopen.la  -L/usr/X11/lib -R/usr/X11/lib -L/opt/local/lib -lfreetype -lz -o ltdl/libltdlc.la  ltdl/loaders/ltdl_libltdlc_la-preopen.lo ltdl/ltdl_libltdlc_la-lt__alloc.lo ltdl/ltdl_libltdlc_la-lt_dlloader.lo ltdl/ltdl_libltdlc_la-lt_error.lo ltdl/ltdl_libltdlc_la-ltdl.lo ltdl/ltdl_libltdlc_la-slist.lo ltdl/argz.lo 
ranlib: archive member: ltdl/.libs/libltdlc.a(argz.o) cputype (7) does not match previous archive members cputype (16777223) (all members must match)
ranlib: archive member: ltdl/.libs/libltdlc.a(argz.o) cputype (7) does not match previous archive members cputype (16777223) (all members must match)
make[1]: *** [ltdl/libltdlc.la] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm alread out of my depth, but now I'm totally stuck! Any ideas?

Comment: The confusion caused by a vote 'belongs on superuser.com' is troublesome -- what the hell does belong on StackOverflow any more?  It was *much* simpler when there was just one place to look.

Answer (score 1):

My general trick for ensuring things compile 64-bit (or 32-bit, mutatis mutandis) is:

```
CC="gcc -m64" ...other environment...  ./configure  ...configure arguments...
```

This treats the C compiler (add `CXX="g++ -m64"` if you need C++ too) as a 64-bit compiler by virtue of the '`-m64`' argument.  It may or may not be elegant - it is what I use on both Solaris and MacOS X.  There can also be package-specific options to the `./configure` script that control this (occasionally override this); use '`./configure --help`' to see whether this is so.

The problem looks to be that the `libtool` was set up as a 32-bit system.  Before changing to the 64-bit build, make sure you've run '`make distclean`' to get rid of all the debris - or remove the build directory altogether and re-extract the material from the tar-ball.  Run the configure process as shown - the chances are decent that will be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `LDFLAGS="-arch x86_64" CXXFLAGS="-arch x86_64"` to your `./configure` calls and it should compile fine.

That said I think you'll end up with a half-working ImageMagick install unless you also make sure libjpeg and libpng are compiled with 64bits as well.

You might try starting httpd using the i386 (32bit) binary instead by adding `/usr/bin/arch -i386` to `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`.  Or you can use lipo to convert `/usr/sbin/httpd` to a i386 only binary.