# Compiling 64-bit FLAC/libFLAC in OS X Lion

Tags: makefile, osx-lion, 64-bit, configure

I'd like to use the libFLAC dynamic libraries in an app I'm trying to build, but I'm not too familiar with `configure` and `make` arguments to actually get FLAC to compile.

I have tried to `CC="gcc -m64" CXX="g++ -m64" ./configure` and that appears to run fine without issues, but when I run `make`, I still get

```
[...lots of output with seemingly no errors...]  
/usr/bin/ranlib: archive member: .libs/libFLAC.a(bitreader_asm.o) cputype (7) does not match previous archive members cputype (16777223) (all members must match)
/usr/bin/ranlib: archive member: .libs/libFLAC.a(cpu_asm.o) cputype (7) does not match previous archive members cputype (16777223) (all members must match)
/usr/bin/ranlib: archive member: .libs/libFLAC.a(fixed_asm.o) cputype (7) does not match previous archive members cputype (16777223) (all members must match)
/usr/bin/ranlib: archive member: .libs/libFLAC.a(lpc_asm.o) cputype (7) does not match previous archive members cputype (16777223) (all members must match)
/usr/bin/ranlib: archive member: .libs/libFLAC.a(stream_encoder_asm.o) cputype (7) does not match previous archive members cputype (16777223) (all members must match)
ranlib .libs/libFLAC.a
ranlib: archive member: .libs/libFLAC.a(bitreader_asm.o) cputype (7) does not match previous archive members cputype (16777223) (all members must match)
ranlib: archive member: .libs/libFLAC.a(cpu_asm.o) cputype (7) does not match previous archive members cputype (16777223) (all members must match)
ranlib: archive member: .libs/libFLAC.a(fixed_asm.o) cputype (7) does not match previous archive members cputype (16777223) (all members must match)
ranlib: archive member: .libs/libFLAC.a(lpc_asm.o) cputype (7) does not match previous archive members cputype (16777223) (all members must match)
ranlib: archive member: .libs/libFLAC.a(stream_encoder_asm.o) cputype (7) does not match previous archive members cputype (16777223) (all members must match)
ranlib: for architecture: x86_64 file: .libs/libFLAC.a(float.o) has no symbols  
make[4]: *** [libFLAC.la] Error 1  
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1  
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1  
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1  
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds similar to [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185287/compiling-imagemagick-as-64bit-under-os-x)

Comment: @user1118321 Actually, the answer to that question is where I got the configure flags that I've used above, but they do not seem to work in this situation.

Comment: It is different from the linked issue in that in this case, you are compiling C files as 64-bit by default (it is so since Snow Leopard and continues with Lion. `CC="gcc -m64" CXX="g++ -m64"` doesn't do anything) and your problem arrives when trying to link these files with object files that were generated from IA32 assembly. You could try `CC="gcc -m32" CXX="g++ -m32" ./configure`: at least it will have some effects (I can't guarantee they will be positive).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get this to compile on Lion, disable assembler optimizations:

`% ./configure --disable-asm-optimizations`

Comment: Works on Mountain Lion (10.8) as well.